# UNIX, how to maintain directory structure?

Tags: linux, unix

I want to create an empty directory structure `bar2` from a nonempty directory tree `bar1`. 
Both `bar1` and `bar2` are at the same hierarchical level. How can I use `mkdir` in an efficient manner so that intermediate directories are automatically created?

1. To create a directory list from bar1 with find and order it if necessary.
2. Using `awk`, remove all branches from the list so that I can run `mkdir only on the leaves.
3. Run `mkdir` with the list to replicate the directory structure of bar1

Comment: Why is identifying only leaves necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hard part of your question (how to list only leaf directories) has been [asked before on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574403/list-all-leaf-subdirectories-in-linux). You can use the `find`/`awk` combo there and run `mkdir -p` on each result:

```
[bar1] $ find . -type d | sort | awk '$0 !~ last {print last} {last=$0} END {print last}' | xargs -Ix mkdir -p ../bar2/x
```

Answer (score 6):

```
cd bar1
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p '../bar2/{}' \;
```

Comment: This doesn't remove the leaves, it runs mkdir for each directory

Comment: Er. s/leaves/branches/ in my comment. That is, for the directory structure bar2/a/b/c it will run three mkdirs instead of one

Comment: Thanks for all your answers and comments. They were very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) instead:

```
rsync -r -f '+ */' -f '- *' bar1 bar2
```

which is, more *verbose*:

```
rsync --verbose --recursive --include '*/' --exclude '*' bar1 bar2
```