# How to keep directory structure with aria2?

Tags: linux, unix, aria2

I need to download files simultaneously- wget doesn't support that so I want to try aria2. But I don't see an option in aria2 to keep directory structure.

Comment: This question actually belongs to superuser & co

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Determine the directory structure first, 
then build and use a download description file:

```
aria2c -i uri.txt
```

where `uri.txt` might contain

```
http://serverA/file1.iso http://mirror-serverB/file1.iso
# parameters must begin with a space, otherwise it's treatened as url!
 dir=/downloads/a
# not mandatory
 out=file1.iso

http://serverA/file2.iso http://mirror-serverB/file2.iso
 dir=/downloads/b
 out=file2.iso
```

Keep in mind that aria2 is a download util - not an sync util, like rsync or lftp.

Referencing an `rsync` answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4147263/1163786
and an `lftp` answer: https://superuser.com/a/305236.

Comment: `wget`  is also a download util and can keep the directory structure. Downthemall is also a download util, and can keep the directory structure. So that is not a reason not to offer the feature.