# How to export files of Baidu pan(baidu net disk) via aria2 without speed limits?

Tags: baidu, aria2

intall chrome extends BaiduExporter, then export aria2 link and download with aria.

- [linux - How to keep directory structure with aria2? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202905/how-to-keep-directory-structure-with-aria2)
- [acgotaku/BaiduExporter: Assistant for Baidu to export download links to aria2/aria2-rpc](https://github.com/acgotaku/BaiduExporter)
- [使用Aria2下载百度网盘和115的资源](https://blog.icehoney.me/posts/2015-01-31-Aria2-download)
- [aria2](https://aria2.github.io/)