# Grouping files by directory branch/leaf

Tags: bash, shell, find

I am new to bash and am having difficulty processing directory tree structures.
I have a directory structure that is as follows

```
I/A/dataA.dat
I/B/dataB.dat
I/C/dataC.dat

II/A/dataA.dat
II/B/dataB.dat
II/C/dataC.dat

III/A/dataA.dat
III/B/dataB.dat
III/C/dataC.dat
```

I now want to process `I/A/dataA.dat` with `I/B/dataB.dat` and likewise `II/A/dataA.dat` with `II/B/dataB.dat` etc (for every case).  But I do not want to process, for example, `I/A/dataA.dat` with `II/B/dataB.dat`.

**What is the best way to find such pairs of files?**

I wish to pass the names of the found pair to a bash function such as follows

```
function process_pair()
{
  fileOne=$1; #for example II/A/data.dat
  fileTwo=$2; #for example II/B/data.dat
  //the rest of the function that processes this pair.
}
```

but I do not know how to get the variables `$1` and `$2`.

I am currently using bash and starting from the `dirs=find $SOURCE -type d -links 2` command (to find all the leaf directories - [adapted from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269798/use-gnu-find-to-show-only-the-leaf-directories)).  I am then trying to loop over these (using substring commands to obtain the directory above).
However, I am finding this difficult and I think there must be a better way.

Comment: This is edging toward the sort of thing you might prefer a fuller scripting language for. The obvious method is to build up a data structure which, for each filename, contains a list of the directories it's appeared in, so that each time you read a directory, you process each file in it along the same-named file in each directory in the corresponding list. This would be really easy in perl, with a hash of arrays, for example.

Comment: Thanks @Jefromi, I will dig out my Perl book if I get no more replies here (it needs a dusting anyway...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readily done in the shell:

```
for dir in I II III; do
    subdirs=()
    for subdir in $dir/*; do subdirs+=("${subdir##*/}"); done
    for (( i=0 ;i<${#subdirs[*]}-1; i++ ));  do
        for (( j=i ;j<${#subdirs[*]} ;j++ ));  do
            a=${subdirs[$i]}
            b=${subdirs[$j]}
            process_pair $dir/$a/data$a.dat $dir/$b/data$b.dat
        done
    done
done
```