# How to list empty folders in linux

Tags: linux

In Linux how do I check all folders in a directory and output the name of all directories that are empty to a list.

Comment: Similar: [Use GNU find to show only the leaf directories](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4269798/55075) at SO

Comment: `man find` explains the different list formats. See `-print ` and `-print0`, for example.

Answer (score 314):

Try the following:

```
find . -type d -empty
```

Comment: You'll need to change '/' to the directory you want to use as your search root.

Comment: Are you sure your directories are really empty? Do ls -a to see hidden (dot) files.

Comment: Thanks! It does work well on my system. To get a sorted list use: `find / -type d -empty | sort -u`

Comment: Incidentally, to remove: find . -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;

Comment: Empty dirs in current dir: `find . -type d -empty`. In addition, empty files: `find . -type f -empty` in current dir and deeper.

Comment: @Scott - why not `find . -type d -empty -delete`?

Comment: Ken, that would work--I didn't know about that option (I usually just get to a point where I can run a command on the right collection of files and start using -exec; I'll have to remember -delete for that next time).

Comment: @KenSharp @scott `-exec rmdir {} \;` scales better than `-delete` .. for a small number of items, it doesn't really matter. For large numbers, it does. Thus, I always use `-exec` because it works well regardless of the number.

Comment: @bubba why would `-exec rmdir {} \;` scale better than `-delete`? In my view, `-delete` is way better, as `find` just deletes the file, instead of spawning another process for each directory to delete

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167823/find-exec-rm-vs-delete/167824 – `-exec rmdir {} +`  *might* scale better as it *could* reduce I/O, but there's no reason I can think of why `-exec rmdir {}` should see any improvement. And only then if `rmdir` isn't updating the filesystem data one by one (which I guess would depend on the filesystem and mount options). There would have to be a LOT of empty directories to notice any difference at all, even on my first 486DX.

Comment: This does not find the folder that has an empty folder inside

Comment: @KenSharp can `find . -type d -empty -delete` also print the deleted dirs in the process

Answer (score 4):

With Zsh, you can do the following:

```
printf '%q\n' ./*/**/(/DN^F)
```

*Replace `.` with the actual path to the directory you want, or remove it if you want to search the entire file system.*

---

From the section called [Glob Qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers):

> F
>
> ‘full’ (i.e. non-empty) directories. Note that the opposite sense `(^F)` expands to empty directories and all non-directories. Use `(/^F)` for empty directories.

- `/` means show directories
- `D` means to also search hidden files (directories in this case)
- `N` Enables null pattern. i.e. the case where it finds no directories should not cause the glob to fail
- `F` means to show non-empty directories
- `^` is used to negate the meaning of the qualifier(s) following it

To put them all into an array:

```
empties=(./*/**/(/DN^F))
```

---

Bonus: To remove all the *empty* directories:

```
rmdir ./*/**/(/DN^F)
```

Looks like we finally found a useful case for `rmdir`!