# List the last folders in a recursive way

Tags: recursion, find

I have a hard disk with a lot of folders and sub folders.
The format is like that :

/ genre1 / artist / set of pictures1 / list of .jpg

but it can also be

/ genre2 / set of pictures2 / list of .jpg

I would like to get the full list of paths where the .jpg are. They are the last folder of each folder tree.

How can i do it with a shell script ?
I was trying to use "find" with mindepth or maxdepth and -type d but i can't tell how many depth levels i must look for .. it can change.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-links` test as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4269862/3076724)

```
find / -type d -links 2 -exec \
  find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.jpg' -printf "%h\n" -quit \
\;
```

If you're not using `gnu find`, you can do something like

```
find / -type d -links 2 -exec \
  bash -c 'shopt -s dotglob nullglob; a=(*.jpg); ((${#a[@]}>0)) && echo "$1"' bash {} \
\;
```