# Remove line (omit from the output) if the previous line is a prefix

Tags: bash, awk

This is very similar to the question "[remove duplicate lines with similar prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48656682/remove-duplicate-lines-with-similar-prefix)" but it's the other way around:

Given an input of *sorted* strings (in this case, directories) like:

```
a/
a/b/c/
a/d/
bar/foo/
bar/foo2/
c/d/
c/d/e/
```

I want to remove the lines from the output, **if the previous line is a prefix of the current line**. In this case, the output would be:

```
a/
bar/foo/
bar/foo2/
c/d/
```

This would be pretty easy to code in Python etc, but in this case I am in shell environment (bash, sort, sed, awk...). (Re-sorting is fine.)

Comment: Is `a/b/c/` a prefix of `a/d/`?

Comment: Since `a/` exists `a/d/` should not exist in the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use awk:

```
awk '{if(k && match($0, k))next; k="^"$0}1' file
```

k="^"$0 to anchor the pattern to the beginning of the string.

Probably need `NF>0` before the main block in case there are EMPTY lines.

**Update:** there could be issues if regex meta characters exist in the variable `k`, the below line without using regex should be better:

```
awk '{if(k && index($0, k)==1)next; k=$0}1' file
```

**Update-2:** thanks @Ed, I've adjusted the 2nd method to cover non-empty lines which evaluated to zeros (empty lines will be kept as-is though):

```
awk '{if(k!="" && index($0,k)==1)next;k=$0}1' file
```

Comment: @EdMorton, good catch-up, the 2nd one does have issue when the lines are zero or empty. the first one should be fine due to the prefixed `^`.

Answer (score 2):

Perl 1-liner.  Loop over the input lines `-n` and then execute `-e` the following program, checking to see if the beginning of the current line matches the last line, printing the non-matches.

```
perl -ne 'print unless m|^$last|; chomp($last=$_);' file_list.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Bash itself (in fact POSIX shell) provides all you need through *parameter expansion with substring removal*. All you need to do is check whether the line you read matches itself with the prefix removed. If it doesn't, you have a prefixed line, otherwise, you have a non-prefixed line. Then it is a simple matter of outputting the non-prefixed line and setting the prefix to the current line -- and repeat, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

pfx=    ## prefix

## read each line
while read -r line; do 
    ## if no prefix or line matches line with prefix removed
    if [ -z "$pfx" -o "$line" = "${line#$pfx}" ]
    then
        printf "%s\n" "$line"   ## output lile
        pfx="$line"             ## set prefix to line
    fi
done < "$1"
```

(**note:** if there is a chance that an input file that does not contain a POSIX end-of-file, e.g. a `'\n'` on the final line of the file, then you should check the contents of line as a condition of your `while`, e.g. `while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do ...` )

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat string.txt
a/
a/b/c/
a/d/
bar/foo/
bar/foo2/
c/d/
c/d/e/
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash nonprefix.sh string.txt
a/
bar/foo/
bar/foo2/
c/d/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==1 || index($0,prev)!=1{prev=$0; print}' file
a/
bar/foo/
bar/foo2/
c/d/
```

Comment: this one will not survive if the first line is EMPTY

Comment: I get what you're saying but we don't know if this will behave correctly or not since the OP hasn't told us what the correct behavior is if the previous line is empty. In other words it's Undefined Behavior so anything a tool does is compliant/correct :-).