# how to exclude printing in bash a line that has no sub directory path compared to other similar paths?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Team,
my situation is like I have to pull paths that are with subdirectorys and exclude printing the parent directory path alone.

so example output

```
src/services/sam-agent #< should not be printed
src/services/sam-agent/auth
src/services/sam-agent/certs
src/services/sam-agent/server
src/services/jam-controller #< should not be printed
src/services/jam-controller/api
src/services/jam-controller/client
src/services/wam-controller/api #< should not be printed
src/services/wam-controller/api/client
src/services/wam-controller/api/server
```

expected

```
src/services/sam-agent/auth
src/services/sam-agent/certs
src/services/sam-agent/server
src/services/jam-controller/api
src/services/jam-controller/client
```

I got above by below expression not sure what modifications I can make to get above output.

`find src/services/ -type f -name 'BUILD.bazel' | sed -r 's|/[^/]+$||' |sort |uniq|grep -e '*-controller'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use GNU find to show only the leaf directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269798/use-gnu-find-to-show-only-the-leaf-directories)

Comment: Ah, I just noticed you're searching for BUILD.bazel files and getting their directories, so that probably won't work.

Comment: This looks to me more like a general programming question, i.e. to find an algorithm. Here a starting point: Read the input line by line. Make sure that in your loop you always have the current line **and** the previous line in a variable. If the previous line is a prefix of the current line, go to the next iteration. Otherwise print the previous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you want:

```
$ cat file | sort | tac | awk '{sub("/[^/]+$","")} index(prev,$0"/") != 1{print} {prev=$0}'
src/services/wam-controller/api/server
src/services/wam-controller/api/client
src/services/sam-agent/server
src/services/sam-agent/certs
src/services/sam-agent/auth
src/services/jam-controller/client
src/services/jam-controller/api
```

Replace `cat file` with `find src/services/ -type f -name 'BUILD.bazel'` to give this input:

```
$ cat file
src/services/sam-agent/BUILD.bazel
src/services/sam-agent/auth/BUILD.bazel
src/services/sam-agent/certs/BUILD.bazel
src/services/sam-agent/server/BUILD.bazel
src/services/jam-controller/BUILD.bazel
src/services/jam-controller/api/BUILD.bazel
src/services/jam-controller/client/BUILD.bazel
src/services/wam-controller/api/BUILD.bazel
src/services/wam-controller/api/client/BUILD.bazel
src/services/wam-controller/api/server/BUILD.bazel
```

The above assumes that none of your directory/file names contain newlines.

Comment: what is an example of newline? i did not get it.

Comment: `> $'foo\nbar'` will create a file whose name contains a newline.

Comment: can you please explain all your params?

Comment: also, can you please help me get the reverse of this output? like parent dir should be printed instead?

Comment: asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76049937/how-to-exclude-printing-in-bash-a-line-that-has-only-parent-path-and-exclude-all

Comment: Regarding [can you please explain all your params?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76040169/how-to-exclude-printing-in-bash-a-line-that-has-no-sub-directory-path-compared-t/76044394?noredirect=1#comment134124703_76044394) - I think the code is pretty self-explanatory if you execute it one step at a time from left to right to see what each command does. Is there any particular part of it that isn't clear?

Answer (score 2):

`find` has a flexible syntax which allows you to articulate many constraints on what you want to have printed.

Your requirements are unclear, but reading from your expected results, I would guess something like

```
find src/services/ -mindepth 2 type f -path '*-controller/*' -name 'BUILD.bazel' -exec dirname {} \;
```

If you have GNU `find` (as you often will on e.g. Linux) you can replace the last `-exec` part with

```
... -printf '%h\n'
```

which will use an internal function from GNU `find` instead of run an external process on each found path, which is generally a useful improvement.

(You could reduce the number of external processes with a more complex `-exec` but I'm guessing you don't really need to optimize this.)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
num=3
<INPUT> | awk -v num=$num -F/ 'NF>num' file
```

`-v` allow to pass variables to `awk` as `key=value`

```
LESS='+/^ +-v' man awk
```

> -v var=val
> --assign var=val
> Assign the value val to the variable var, before execution of the program  begins.  Such variable values are available to the BEGIN rule of an AWK program.

Comment: thanks super quick. well, if parent has 4 sub dirs and not 3 always? hope i am not confusing.

Comment: I answered exactly to your needs. If you have another question, feel free to create another thread. You can modify 3 with the level you need. Usually, the way to thanks here is by accepting/voting up answer(s).

Comment: indeed your answer works but will wait if someone can provide a dynamic answer that takes care of all cases. so will upvote for now.

Comment: am evaluating .. will update, unable to find on google what `vmax` is? or if you can explain your params would be helpful.

Comment: i am unable to vote your answer. i accepted below solution as it seems dynamic to me. let me know how can i give you 1 vote?

Comment: no when i do upvote. it shows me -1 and then back to 0

Comment: i mentioned above right? when i upvote, it shows me -1 then back to 0.

Comment: btw can you answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76049937/how-to-exclude-printing-in-bash-a-line-that-has-only-parent-path-and-exclude-all

but it has to be similar to used command and just reverse of it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can extract the **directory paths** that are not part of a longer one from a list of **file paths** with `awk`:

```bash
find some/path -type f |
awk -F / '
    {
        nf = (type == "d" ? NF : NF-1)
        dir = sep = ""
        for (i = 1; i <= nf; i++) {
            dir = dir sep $i
            sep = FS
            ++arr[dir]
        }
        --arr[dir]
    }
    END {
        for (dir in arr)
            if (arr[dir] == 0)
                print dir
    }
'
```

<sup>**note:** by default it processes **file paths** but you can make it accept **directory paths** as input by adding the parameter `-v type=d` to `awk`</sup>

The solution is 100% generic so it should yield the expected result when processing your `find` command:

```bash
find src/services/ -type f -name 'BUILD.bazel' | awk ... | sort
```

```
src/services/jam-controller/api
src/services/jam-controller/client
src/services/sam-agent/auth
src/services/sam-agent/certs
src/services/sam-agent/server
src/services/wam-controller/api/client
src/services/wam-controller/api/server
```

Now, as @triplee suggested, if you want to exclude the `wam-controller` directory from the output then you can use other predicates in the `find` command:

```bash
find src/services/ ! -path '*/wam-controller/*' -type f -name 'BUILD.bazel' | ...
```