# how to exclude printing in bash a line that has only parent path and exclude all subdir paths

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Team, I asked reverse of this question and it was answered here. [how to exclude printing in bash a line that has no sub directory path compared to other similar paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76040169/how-to-exclude-printing-in-bash-a-line-that-has-no-sub-directory-path-compared-t/76041373#76041373)

in this question I want to do reverse of it.

I want reverse of this below.

```
cat file | sort | tac |awk '{sub("/[^/]+$","")} index(prev,$0"/") != 1{print} {prev=$0}'
```

where `file` actually represents the output of a `find` command:

```
find src/services/ -type f -name 'BUILD.bazel'
```

and so contains:

```
$ cat file
src/services/sam-agent/BUILD.bazel
src/services/sam-agent/auth/BUILD.bazel
src/services/sam-agent/certs/BUILD.bazel
src/services/sam-agent/server/BUILD.bazel
src/services/jam-controller/BUILD.bazel
src/services/jam-controller/api/BUILD.bazel
src/services/jam-controller/client/BUILD.bazel
src/services/wam-controller/api/BUILD.bazel
src/services/wam-controller/api/client/BUILD.bazel
src/services/wam-controller/api/server/BUILD.bazel
```

The desired command when run on the above input should output

```
src/services/sam-agent
src/services/jam-controller
src/services/wam-controller
```

i.e. expected prints only parents and no sub dirs:

```
src/services/sam-agent #< should be printed
src/services/sam-agent/auth
src/services/sam-agent/certs
src/services/sam-agent/server
src/services/jam-controller #< should be printed
src/services/jam-controller/api
src/services/jam-controller/client
src/services/wam-controller/api #< should obe printed
src/services/wam-controller/api/client
src/services/wam-controller/api/server
```

tried answer 1 and got below. still shows sub dir and not just `src/services/rams`

`cat /tmp/t.log | sort | tac | awk '{if ($0 in seen) print; else {sub("/[^/]+$", ""); seen[$0]}}'`

```
src/services/rams/store/postgres
src/services/rams
```

sample t.log

```
src/services/rams
src/services/rams/integration
src/services/rams/keys
src/services/rams/migrations
src/services/rams/mocks
src/services/rams/server
src/services/rams/smoke
src/services/rams/store
src/services/rams/store/postgres
src/services/rams/store/postgres/mocks
src/services/rams/tools/keyrotate
src/services/rams/tools/secretmanager
src/services/rams/vault
```

Comment: Your previous question and this one were both missing the actual input you have (the output of your `find` command) so I edited this question to add it. Feel free to edit it again if you think it could be explained better.

Comment: Shouldn't `src/services/wam-controller/` in your expected output be `src/services/wam-controller/api`?

Comment: Why would the output for `t.log` only be `src/services/rams` instead of `src/services/rams/store`, `src/services/rams`, and `src/services`?

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
cat file | sort | awk 'index($0, prev"/") != 1 {print; prev = $0}'
```

Replace `cat file` with `find src/services/ -type f -name 'BUILD.bazel'`.

- the input is sorted so the parent path appears first.
- `index($0, prev"/")` returns `1` if `prev"/"` is a substring
  of `$0`, meaning `$0` is a child of `prev`. If not, print `$0`
  as a parent.
- the trailing `/` in `prev"/"` anchors the string to avoid a pseudo-match.
- the variable `prev` is updated *only if* `$0` is a parent.

Comment: thanks tried but got subdir again. am posting your solution result log in my question.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I may not have well considered the case of
multiple depths of the subdirectories. Would you please try the fixed code?
BR.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `!=` to `==` in your existing command:

```
$ cat file | sort | tac | awk '{sub("/[^/]+$","")} index(prev,$0"/") == 1{print} {prev=$0}'
src/services/wam-controller/api
src/services/sam-agent
src/services/jam-controller

$ cat t.log | sort | tac | awk '{sub("/[^/]+$","")} index(prev,$0"/") == 1{print} {prev=$0}'
src/services/rams/store
src/services/rams
src/services
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this directory tree:

```
tree ../src
../src
└── services
    ├── jam-controller
    │   ├── BUILD.bazel
    │   ├── api
    │   │   └── BUILD.bazel
    │   └── client
    │       └── BUILD.bazel
    ├── sam-agent
    │   ├── BUILD.bazel
    │   ├── auth
    │   │   └── BUILD.bazel
    │   ├── certs
    │   │   └── BUILD.bazel
    │   └── server
    │       └── BUILD.bazel
    └── wam-controller
        └── api
            ├── BUILD.bazel
            ├── client
            │   └── BUILD.bazel
            └── server
                └── BUILD.bazel

13 directories, 10 files
```

You can get the directories that have the file `BUILD.bazel` and also have a subdirectory with Bash directly (no need for `find`):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

for fn in src/**/BUILD.bazel; do
    parent="$(dirname "$fn")"
    ls "$parent"/*/ &>/dev/null && echo "$parent"
done
```

Prints:

```
src/services/jam-controller
src/services/sam-agent
src/services/wam-controller/api
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use GNU `find` you can try:

```
$ find src/services/* -type f -name 'BUILD.bazel' -printf '%H\n' | sort | uniq
src/services/jam-controller
src/services/sam-agent
src/services/wam-controller
```

Add the `-mindepth 1` option if there can be a `src/services/BUILD.bazel` file and you want to skip it:

```
find src/services/* -mindepth 1 -type f -name 'BUILD.bazel' -printf '%H\n' | sort | uniq
```