# regex to find path under parent directory

Tags: awk, sed

Team,

I have this expression that finds all the bazel but I want to list only the parent dir that has it. how could i?

```
find src/services/ -type f -name 'BUILD.bazel' | sed -r 's|/[^/]||' |sort |uniq |grep -e etl-domain/
```

output

```
srcervices/etl-domain/api/BUILD.bazel
srcervices/etl-domain/BUILD.bazel
```

expected output

```
srcervices/etl-domain/BUILD.bazel
```

Comment: If you `want to list only the parent dir that has it`, the command will be:
`find src/services/ -type f -name 'BUILD.bazel' | sed -r 's|/[^/]*$||' | sort -u | grep etl-domain`
and the expected output should be:
`src/services/etl-domain src/services/etl-domain/api`.

Comment: What's this `srcervices` in your expected output? And if you want a file named `BUILD.bazel` in a directory named `src/services/etl-domain` why do you use `find`, `sed`, `sort`, `uniq` and `grep`? Why not just testing if it exists with `f="src/services/etl-domain/BUILD.bazel" && [ -f "$f" ] && echo "$f"`?

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76049937/1745001) with the file name stuck on the end?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to exclude printing in bash a line that has only parent path and exclude all subdir paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76049937/how-to-exclude-printing-in-bash-a-line-that-has-only-parent-path-and-exclude-all)

Comment: it is different because in those questions there is BUILD.bazel not to be printed and in this question, I just wanted path to be printed keeping bazel as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` has a `maxdepth` parameter, which makes it possible to define the depth of your search. In order just to see the subdirectories, but not deeper, you can use:

```
find <directory> -maxdepth 1 ...
```

In your case, this becomes:

```
find src/services/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'BUILD.bazel' ...
```